# Swift 2.0 understanding how animation with duration works in animation closure

Tags: ios, swift, animation, closures

`UIView.animationWithDuration` is easy to use:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
    self.someView.alpha = 1.0
}
```

How does the function update the variables in the closure to animate instead of just jumping in this case to `alpha = 1.0` on the first iteration?

Comment: What do you mean "how"? You said to animate and this is an animatable property, so it animates because you said so! It creates an animation at the end of the transaction and hands it off to the animation server. What kind of information are you asking for?

Comment: How could I structure my own object then to animate or have iterative properties in swift using closures?

Comment: That's a great question. Why didn't you ask that question?

Comment: It looks like the same question from here with "How does the function update the variable..." but I guess there's always room for confusion and down votes :]

Comment: lol really, I'm surprised your not asking for a cash prize too. It's cool matt you can hold on to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because of the special design of CALayer. Every CALayer has two conceptual layers, both exposed as properties. There is the `modelLayer` which is what you access and modify through properties like `someView.alpha` and generally holds the state of the layer. The model layer updates immediately when you modify related properties, whether or not you're inside a UIView animation block. Then there is also the `presentationLayer` which is actually what gets rendered by the system. The presentation layer usually mirrors the model layer, except when animating. I don't know the specifics, but `UIView.animateWithDuration` does something to tell CoreAnimation, "when I run this animation block, record the changes in the model layer (diff before and after), and then apply them incrementally to the presentation layer over the given duration".

This is why `someView.alpha` is immediately updated despite the animation not having finished, because your code is interacting with the model layer. If you access the presentation layer, you will see that the updated value is applied incrementally.

Comment: That's not true. You can make your own custom view properties work with `UIView.animateWithDuration`.

Comment: @matt Sorry, you are right. I removed that part of the answer since OP did not explicitly ask about animating his own properties.

Comment: And he continues to refuse to ask about it, even though that is actually what he wants to know.

Comment: @PatrickGoley thanks, this is a great explanation of what I asked, and it gives me a direction to read into in the docs.